# AEM: add conditional classes to Decoration Tag

Tags: javascript, css, aem, sightly, aem-6

I'm using AEM 6.5

my html file is

```
<div
  data-sly-test="${empty && wcmmode.edit}"
  class="cq-placeholder"
  data-emptytext="${component.title}"
></div>

<sly data-sly-test="${!empty}">
  <section class="band full-bleed">
    ....
  </section>
</sly>
```

The generated decoration tag

```
<div class="widget-hero cq-Editable-dom">
....
</div>
```

How can I toggle a class `.show-image` on the decoration tag when `data-sly-test="${!empty}"`, so that it can render like

```
<div class="widget-hero show-image cq-Editable-dom">
....
</div>
```

I've tried:

1. deleting the decoration tag
2. answer #2 in this post: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/312993

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the decoration tag classes from the inner component rendering. You could:

- control it from the caller component (parsys/responsivegrid/container) but that will create a strong dependency between them
- put the desired class(es) on an intermediary tag: decoration -> wrapper -> markup